# In forge viewer, markupgui extension design get obosolete

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using forge viewer version 7.
In that i'm adding markup core extension but in that ui is so obsolete so we want to change that ui but in that case we can only apply css and modify but we want to change the structure of that if that possible and if not then we have idea to make our own markup toolbar and call all the method but in that if we want to change fill and stroke and opacity at that time we can't find any method to handle so can you provide that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI provided with the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore` extension (the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui` extension) is only meant as an example of how you can build your own markup UI. You are actually encouraged to build your own UI using `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui` just as a reference.

Note that you can find the implementation of the basic UI in https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Markup/Markup.js (look at the `MarkupsGui` class and how it uses `this.core` to access the functionality of the `MarkupsCore` extension such as `this.core.enterEditMode()`, or `this.core.copy()` and `this.core.paste()`).